# DreamFactory REST API POST rest/user/session request always returns error in IE9

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, internet-explorer-9

The initial POST rest/user/session request works in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari, but when using Internet Explorer 9 it always returns some sort of error..

When the dataType is set to "json", IE9 gets back a 'no transport' error with a status of 0. When the dataType is set to "jsonp", IE9 gets back an error object with a success XHR status 200 with a parseError.

...

```
        $.ajax({
            url: BASE_PATH + url,
            beforeSend: function (request) {
                request.setRequestHeader("X-DREAMFACTORY-APPLICATION-NAME", APP_NAME);
                request.setRequestHeader("X-DREAMFACTORY-SESSION-TOKEN", sessionStorage.SESSION_TOKEN);
                request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
                request.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
            },
            method: method,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            processData : processData,
            data: newdata,
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
            console.log(arguments);
                $.jStorage.set("unique_session_id",response.session_id);
                sessionStorage.SESSION_TOKEN = response.session_id;
                runApp();
            },
            error: function(response){
                console.log(arguments);         
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

DreamFactory will only communicate successfully in IE10 or above. Implementation of REST, CSS, etc. was insufficient in IE9.

I recommend trying to navigate directly to the REST URI in IE9 to see if the response is returned properly. If so, it's an issue in your ajax script or implementation and not in DSP/IE9 specifically.

Some quick research also indicates to try this:

```
$.support.cors = true;
```